# How does android track allocations?

Tags: android, dalvik

The DDMS has a nice feature of tracking object allocations. I'm wondering how this feature is implemented. Is it done inside the VM? Where can I find the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point is probably [dalvik/vm/AllocTracker.cpp](https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/blob/master/vm/AllocTracker.cpp). Also, look for usages of `dvmTrackAllocation` elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know internals, but here is a link for source code, if you want to walk throuhg.[git source link](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)